# FTP user credentials in iframe

Tags: http, iframe, ftp, passwords

I have an iframe that contains protected ftp address

```
<iframe id="ftpfrm" src="ftp://ftpserver" </iframe>
```

But when I display the page, it doesn't ask for ftp user name and password. The frame displays an error page.
I need to know if there's a way to force the iframe to ask for user credentials, or to pass the user credentials to the uframe tag.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following to login the user (which i would *not* recommend):

```
<iframe id="ftpfrm" src="ftp://user:password@ftpserver" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This works only in old browsers, besides it's not secured to send user credentials in  URL